# How to update Fragment editText value with the values getting from GraphJSONObjectCallback's onCmpleted method

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to integrate login via facebook in my android app, all i want is when a user successfully logged in the response I get should be automatically set to my `EditText` that I have created in view. I got the response through `GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()` inside `onCompleted` (like name, email, birthday). Now I want to set these values to my `EditText` fields:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity Response ", response.toString());

                                try {
                                    userName = object.getString("name");
                                    nameBox.setText(userName);
}
```

I debugged the line here,

```
nameBox.setText(userName);
```

is executed successfully but my EditText is still empty. I also tried to run this on

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            //completeRegistration();
                                            EditText eddt = (EditText) parentView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                                            eddt.setText(userName);
}
```

but still doesn't work out.

**EDIT** @Vulovic Vukasin
I cannot provide you complete fragment code it for some privacy reasons but i can give you everything that is related to it
this is in my onCreateView

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        nameBox = (EditText) parentView.findViewById(R.id.name);
 FBloginButton = (LoginButton) parentView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        FBloginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
        // If using in a fragment
        FBloginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization
        // Callback registration
        FBloginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                String s = loginResult.toString();
                // App code
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                // Facebook Email address
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity Response ", response.toString());

                                try {
                                    userName = object.getString("name");
                                    nameBox.setText(userName);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email, gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                String s = "did you just cancel login?";
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exception.printStackTrace();
                // App code
            }
        });

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.

            }
        };
    return parentView;
}
```

Comment: please post whole code for activity and if you have fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you check the docs for EditText, you'll find a setText() method. It takes in a String and a TextView.BufferType. So do this instead

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
editText.setText(username, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);


private void runThread() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            EditText eddt =(EditText)parentView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                            eddt.setText(userName);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the fields received are not null? Also, it might be because of the way you are creating a new runnable. That code might not allow actual changes on the UI, so I will update the answer to the correct way of doing that Runnable @djhiten

Comment: Yes they are not null, i am getting the values in feilds and also the editText is the same where i need that value, the problem is that it is executing successfull but not giving the result

Comment: Alright from your code I can see that you dont really need a runnable. Remove that try catch in the onCompleted. Also, if I were in your place I would try changing or displaying an alert box in the onCompleted just to see if I can do any changes to the main UI. Also, how about you write a private function called updateEditBoxes(pass username, birthday...) and call that on the onCompleted()

Comment: i tried calling a seperate function providing it with the values but doesn't succeed you may have point on showing an alert so that i can confirm that i can work on UI thread but i cannot remove try catch block as it says "you must handle org.json.JSONException that may can occur while accessing value from JSONObject" the most i can do is, to send this Complete json object to a seperate function where i can use try catch, but first let me try with an alertbox inside onCompleted

Comment: Then keep the try and catch and just try changing something on the main UI, like change a button text would work too

Comment: so yes i tried
    ``Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(), userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`` and its working but setText still not working

Comment: How about changing a button's text?

Comment: i don't have any button in my view all are imageview on which i have asigned on click event handler even facebook button is hidden i have shown a seperate image for facebook on click of that i perform facebook button click, plus i don't thnk that will work

Comment: yes it is changing, i tried changing facebook button text to "log out" and it has been changed

Comment: Very weird behavior.. do you want the user to be able to change the details after they are pulled from facebook? If not just use a TextView instead